# Does installing sybase Linux 16.0 version in silent mode change the libraries

Tags: linux, database, installation, libraries, sap-ase

Would there be any change in the way the library files are generated when we select the different mode of installation of sybase linux 16.0,modes ike silent or console mode..
to be precise do their generation have any effect if we change the configuration parameters..if so how..

I have already been through the installation guide but it doesn't specify any information on that..

Comment: This is more of a dba.stackexchange.com topic..FYI.  Marking it for move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console mode, and GUI mode have the same default locations, so libraries will be put in the same spots, assuming you choose identical options.

Silent mode depends on a response file which needs to be generated using either the GUI or console installation.  The response file will match the installation options you choose, so it will not change the libraries.

Check out [Section 7.4 in the Linux installation guide](http://help.sap.com/Download/Multimedia/ASE_16.0_rev04/aseiglin.pdf) for more details on creating and editing the response file.

Comment: thanks for the info..
Apart from the SAP support do you know where i can get 32-bit Linux libraries for sybase..i have goggled but didn't get any where..
Any reference would also be of great help :)

Comment: When you say libraries, are you talking for developing applications using Open Client architecture? Can you be a bit more specific on what you are looking for - libraries can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: yes..developing through open client...the application which i am working needs 32-bit Linux lib's and recently some of them got corrupted....after going through several sites got to know that SAP has stopped providing 32-bit Linux version..so I am installing 16.0 and trying to use these 64-bit lib's..
Do you know where i can get 32-bit version lib's?

Comment: The product you are looking for is Open Server.  It includes the SDK and libraries necessary for development.  The 16.0 (and 15.7) version only includes 32 bit support for Windows.  If you have support for your software, you may want to log a ticket and find out if they can provide you an older version of the SDK with the 32-bit Linux versions.

Answer (score 0):

No libraries differences between silent mode and console mode, unless you select different installation mode before installation. The installation mode should contain typical/full/custom.